# How do I change my <header> background image after a certain amount of time

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

here is my current html code:

http://pastebin.com/CRNVzhZd

I need to make it so that the background image changes automatically to a few images after a few seconds as so:

image 1 = 3 seconds
after 3 seconds change image 1 to image 2
show image 2 for 3 seconds etc....

How can this be done? jquery? Ajax?

Comment: jQuery. 'Nuff said. Post something you've tried and you may g get a more meaningful response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this could be a solution [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/MNPXM/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr=['http://s14.postimg.org/p6ds42qb5/foto22.jpg','http://s17.postimg.org/or0zqcqov/foto33.jpg']
    var count=-1
    function changeImage(){
        count++
        if(count>=arr.length){
            count=0
            }
        $('#head').attr('style','background-image:url('+arr[count]+')') 
        }


    setInterval(function() { changeImage() },1000)
})
</script>
```

If you need to add other images you must enter their location within the array.